# Excel Macro Copy Paste from one sheet to other

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a macro which does few calculation in another workbook and creates a new sheet where it writes the final data.

In the last step, the values from the new sheet should be copied to the current workbook where the Macro is written.

I have written the following line to do the paste activity. But my problem is, each time the data gets pasted in different places in the workbook. Is there a way for me to paste values starting from particular column

```
ThisWorkbook.Activate 
Sheets(1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if its a static range:

```
Range("B3:D7").Select  'Or the range you need
Selection.Copy         ' Copy that selection
Sheets("yoursheet").Select   'Select the sheet or workbook where you will paste info
ActiveSheet.Paste ' Paste data
```

Tell me how it goes.

To select the range in destination Sheet use this order :

```
Sheets("yoursheet").Select 
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: You could reduce that to a single line `Range("B3:D7").Copy Sheets("yoursheet").Range("A1")` although workbook and sheet references should be included everywhere.

Comment: @SJR do you not need the `Destination:=` before `Sheets("yoursheet")`?

Comment: @mo.h - no you don't need to specify parameter names, though it can be useful if you want to explain your code.

Comment: I am using the usedrange to copy the data. But is there any way I can specify the range in destination before pasting it?

Comment: @user3488285 I updated my answer so you can check and try